# Nhibernate HQL where IN query

Tags: nhibernate, hql, castle-activerecord

Im trying to return a SimpleQuery list that queries a single table and uses IN.
I can get this to work using

```
return new List<Jobs>(
    ActiveRecordMediator<Jobs>.FindAll(Expression.In("ServiceId", ids))
);
```

However this is really really really slow. So id like to do something like this

```
SimpleQuery<Job> query = 
    new SimpleQuery<Job>(@"from Job as j where ? in (j.ServiceId)", ids);

return new List<Job>(query.Execute());
```

However I cant get the SimpleQuery to work. I cant find any documentation covering this and was hoping someone out there would be able to help.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have a look at the NHibernate HQL documentation [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql).

I'm guessing from your code, that you're after a HQL query to return all jobs where the job.ServiceID in a list of ids.

Maybe something along the lines,

```
IQuery q = s.CreateQuery("from Job as j where j.ServiceId in (:serviceIds)");
q.SetParameterList("serviceIds", ids);
```

BTW, have you heard of the [NHibernate Lambda Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/nhlambdaextensions/) project?
Below is an example of the IN query done using the the mentioned library. Might be something interesting to look at as an alternative to using HQL.

```
DetachedCriteria after =
    DetachedCriteria.For<Person>()
        .Add(SqlExpression.In<Person>(p => p.Name, 
          new string[] { "name1", "name2", "name3" }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I edited my query based on your reply

SimpleQuery<Job> query = new SimpleQuery<Job>(
                    @"from Job as j where j.SecondName = (:name) and ServiceId in (:serviceIds)");
                query.SetParameter("serviceIds", ids);
                query.SetParameter("name", name);
                return new List<Job>(query.Execute());

The only issue now is the int array of ids i'm passing in. The field  in the database is type int, if i use IN on any of the string fields it works fine and if i pass a single int value it works. How can I pass an array? Thanks

Comment: Also this might be useful to you as well
http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-queryinterface