# How to use Contains() in a many-to-many scenario?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Nhibernate 3.0

Hi,

Classic blog scenario:

- Blog

  - Tags
- Posts

  - Tags (many-to-many)

When I want to only show the posts containing a specific tag I use the `Contains()` function like this:

```
var tag = session.Query<Tag>().Single(x => x.Name == "C#");
var postsByTag = session.Query<Post>().Where(x => x.Tags.Contains(tag));
```

This works like a charm and NHibernate generates the right SQL.

However, now my user wants to get all posts containing a minimum of one of multiple tags. I ended up doing it like this:

```
var tags = session.Query<Tag>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Nhibernate"));
var postsByTag = session.Query<Post>().Where(x => x.Tags.Any(t => tags.Contains(t)));
```

This works as expected, `postsByTag` only contains posts that contains one of the selected tags. My problem with this is NHibernate unfortunately don't know how to translate this to SQL, so instead of using `WHERE IN` it simply gets all posts from the database, and then do the filtering afterwards. This is a huge performance issue for me, because the blog can possibly have millions of posts.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whether it is the correct answer or not I would be very interseted if my LINQ statements in my Answer below work for you. LINQ gives developers a lot of rope to hang themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having worked on LINQ providers I can understand its problems. Thankfully though there is a better way than contains and any.

```
from post in session.Query<Post>
from tag in post.Tags 
where tag.Name.StartsWith("blah")
select post
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. This forced NHibernate to generate the exact SQL I was looking for (WHERE IN). Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**HQL**

You should take a look at Hibernate Query Language, there's actually a few ways to do it using HQL or even using an Alias and ICriterion.

- [Nhibernate HQL where IN query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401950/nhibernate-hql-where-in-query)
- http://ayende.com/blog/4023/nhibernate-queries-examples

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm aware of that, but I was really hoping for a LINQ solution. So far I have totally avoided using HQL and I really like to continue doing that :P

Comment: I don't see why you would insist on performing LINQ queries over HQL when HQL was built specifically so that you can optimise your final query to the db to avoid n+1 selects.  This is something that you can't do with EF, if EF does something you do not like.  You don't have the option to optimise it. [http://ayende.com/blog/4351/nhibernate-vs-entity-framework-4-0](http://ayende.com/blog/4351/nhibernate-vs-entity-framework-4-0)

Comment: @Justin Shield I think you are confusing technologies. LINQ does not equal EntityFramework. LINQ also supports the ability to do explicit joins in order to reduce the selects you are talking about. It is extremely powerful. The issue is that NHibernates LINQ provider implementation could be incomplete.

Comment: I'm not confusing technologies, I just skipped forward a beat and jumped to the conclusion that if you are insisting on using a LINQ provider to perform queries then why not use EF vs NH.  It's the LINQ provider which actually transforms the LINQ query into a DB query, not LINQ itself.  If it was LINQ then your above query should work perfectly (from what I can see).

Comment: @jhovgaard: and why exactly are you avoiding HQL? HQL is the native (N)Hibernate query language, and exposes a much better API than LINQ. If you don't like learning new things, maybe you're in the wrong profession.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon "The issue is that NHibernates LINQ provider implementation could be incomplete" and second. The NHibernate team created a LINQ provider so they obviously saw value in it. The reason _I_ would want to use LINQ is that i can create custom providers that use the same LINQ statements to go over a network, or go to NHibernate. Something you cannot do if you directly use the HQL.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: unfortunately, LINQ is a really leaky abstraction, and you'll find out that's not a very good idea.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon I'm not afraid of learning new technologies, in fact I'm already familiar with HQL. I want to use LINQ rather than HQL by many reasons but mainly because LINQ is strongly typed and a lot easier for my co-workers to maintain (most frontend/all-around devs know LINQ but not HQL).

Comment: HQL is just as strongly typed as LINQ. And even if it's *other* developers that don't want to learn, that's still a bad reason (not to mention there are many subtleties when applying LINQ-to-objects knowledge to NH LINQ)

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon and I strongly disagree. You should discuss this with the NHibernate team. They decided that the LINQ provider was usable, not me :-)