# How to query using criteria to obtain all objects whose propriety is different than any string value in a list?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

Having:

- an entity `Person` which has a propriety `Name`
- a `List<string> names` loaded with some names

How can I query using criteria to obtain all Person instances who have a Name which is not found in the names list?

Thanks for answers!

**Solution:**

```
var myQuery = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
                     .Add(Expression.Not(Expression.In("Name", names));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looking for an In expression, see: 
[Nhibernate HQL where IN query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401950/nhibernate-hql-where-in-query)

That would make your particular case something like:

```
ActiveRecordMediator<Person>.FindAll(Expression.Not(Expression.In("Name", names)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ps = from p in persons
    where !list.Contains(p.Name)
    select p;
```

Try this.

Comment: This is a Linq to object query, not an NHibernate query. Although it works, it wont be efficient